# I want to fine win revenue,loss revenue and open revenue in powerBI DAX query

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want A DAX Query for PowerBI,
there are columns like reference number which is unique,price value and status.so when i want find lost revenue,I have to calculate SUM of price Value then condition is like ... first I have to check status that is "lost deal",then I have to check the value of price value for "lost Deal".if then price value is blank or 0 for "Lost Deal",then i'll check the status that is "Re-quote" and sum it.if then price value is blank or 0 for "RE-Quote",then i'll check the status that is "Captured" and sum it.and if all the values are present for same reference number then I have ti find Average of this.

for Win Revenue,I have to check Price value of  all status like "purchase order received","Re-quote","Captured".if all values are present then find average of them

As in the picture,I have multiple price value for same reference number,so here I have to find average of these amount,(Status will be different)

I just want sum according to these price

Comment: Can you add an example data set and expected outputs? It will be an IF or SWITCH statement, or FILTER on a measure to calculate something

Comment: Where is the picture?